# Tangent spaces at different points in affine space has the same structure

Tags: differential-geometry, affine-geometry, tangent-spaces

In this book [Theoretical Physics][1] the author says

> However because the manifolds are actually affine spaces, in SR and
> Galilean Geometry the tangent spaces at different points share the same
> structure (which is the underlying tangent vector space), and only in
> these cases they can be assimilated to $R^4$: This is the origin of much
> confusion on the subject, and the motivation to start in the GR
> context where the concepts are clearly diferentiated.

Here SR(special relativity ) and Galilean Geometry are affine space.
My question is what does the author means that tangents spaces at different points share the same structure?

Comment: Probably that tangent spaces at distinct points are _canonically_ identified by affine translation (rather than being non-canonically identified by virtue of having the same dimension, which is the situation for most manifolds).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang   what do you  mean by  canonically identified ?. I am not familiar with this terminology

Comment: There's a [precise definition coming from category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation), but the intuitive idea here is, there's an identification relying only on structure inherent in the set-up (translation in an affine space). Compare with the situation of a round sphere in space: Any two tangent planes are isomorphic because they're planes, but given two tangent planes there is no "distinguished" way to identify them.